# Create table while installing my custom module

Tags: 6, database, installation

My custom module name is "person" and its .install file has the following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_install().
 */
function person_install() {

  drupal_install_schema('person');
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema.
 */
function person_schema() {

  // Static (meta) tables.

  $schema['person'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
      'pid'            => array('type' => 'int', 'length' => 11, 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),
      'name' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50, 'not null' => TRUE),
      'city'        => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50, 'not null' => TRUE),
      'country'        => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50, 'not null' => TRUE)
    ),
    'primary key' => array('pid'),
  );
return $schema;
}
```

But when I installed my module the table has not been created.Any thing wrong with this code?

Comment: Did you definitely _install_ the module and not just re-enable it? Enabling/disabling and installing/uninstalling are two separate things with Drupal modules. If you have Drush + Devel try `drush dre person` to be 100% sure. If not, you can do the same thing through the UI. Your code looks right, so it's probably just that the hooks aren't being invoked

Comment: @Clive.Yes two things are different.But am sure I uninstalled and re-installed it.ok will try it out your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schema your setting **pid**  as primary key. You are setting '' value for primary key. Remove that default value for **pid** and try.

Then your code should be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_install().
 */
function person_install() {

  drupal_install_schema('person');
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema.
 */
function person_schema() {

// Static (meta) tables.

$schema['person'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'pid'            => array('type' => 'int', 'length' => 11, 'not null' => TRUE),
    'name' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50, 'not null' => TRUE),
    'city'        => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50, 'not null' => TRUE),
    'country'        => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50, 'not null' => TRUE)
  ),
  'primary key' => array('pid'),
  );
return $schema;
}
```

After edit the code don't disable and enable the module, hook_install will only call at module install process, so you should first disable the module, unistall the module and then install the module again.

Comment: It created table after installation but the pid column is not set as auto increment field.Any idea?

Comment: Change your primary key **type** attribute in to **serial** instead of **int**. Then your code shhould be:
    'pid'            => array('type' => 'serial', 'length' => 11, 'not null' => TRUE),

Comment: remove length attribute and add **size** attribute with primary key. Then your code should be: 'pid' => array('type' => 'serial', 'size' => 'big', 'not null' => TRUE),